# NonlinearStateSpaceModel/OutputResponse gives doubled outputs

Tags: output, nonlinear, control-systems

I want to simulate a pendulum or rather the controlled system.
But `NonlinearStateSpaceModel` or the `OutputResponse` gives weird doubled outputs.

This is my open loop system or the series connection with the controller

```
fSys = {x2, -(g0/l) Sin[x1 + \[Delta]1] - k0/m x2 + 1/(m l^2) u};
sys = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[{fSys, {x1, x2}}, {x1 -> -\[Pi]/2, 
   x2 -> 0}, {u -> 0}]
ctrl = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[{{}, {-k Sign[a1 x1 + x2]}}, {}, {x1, 
   x2}]
sysConnected = SystemsModelSeriesConnect[ctrl, sys, {1, 1}]
```

This are the rules and the commands for output responses.

```
rules = {\[Delta]1 -> \[Pi]/2, a1 -> 1, k ->(*4*)1, m -> .1, l -> 1, 
   k0 -> .02, g0 -> 9.81};

input = .5 UnitStep[t - 10];
tEnd = 50;
orSys = OutputResponse[sys /. rules, input, {t, 0, tEnd}]
orSysConn = OutputResponse[sysConnected /. rules, input, {t, 0, tEnd}]
```

Can someone explain why I get 2 (or 4) output responses? I would expect (1 or 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system *sys* has 1 input and 2 outputs, while *sysConnected* has 2 inputs and 2 outputs.

```
SystemsModelDimensions /@ {sys, sysConnected}
```

> {{1, 2}, {2, 2}}

When you give a scalar as the input to a single-input system, there is no ambiguity. So the output response of *sys* has two elements for the two outputs.

When you give a scalar as the input to a multiple-input system, the input is cycled. So in this case, the responses for input pairs `{input, 0}` and `{0, input}` are given. So the result is a list of two elements, and since there are two outputs each element is a list of two elements. (If you had given `{input}` that would get interpreted as `{input,0}`.)

Comment: Perfect, I never saw a note about this input behaviour. Also, I had some other problems with Mma's feedback concept (positive/negative). For myself it is not very intuitive.

Comment: The example is a bit ways down in the documentation. http://wolfram.com/xid/0g7kxbwzgfy-nrn3sk